How to handle this parcel error that states "Failed to resolve ''
I am currently trying to run npm start to compile a live version of my index.html, however parcel is throwing this error.
    @parcel/core: Failed to resolve '' from './src/styles/scss/main.scss'

    C:\Users\netog\OneDrive\Desktop\Horizons\src\styles\scss\main.scss:30:5

    @parcel/resolver-default: Invalid empty specifier

I am using sass for my styling and am importing all my modules in my main.scss file. Here is my package.json.
    {
 "name": "horizons",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "parcel src/index.html",
 "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
},
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "description": "",
 "devDependencies": {
"@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.12.0",
"parcel": "^2.12.0"
 }
}

here is my main.scss file.
@use 'layout';
@use 'pages';

I am using index files with forwarded partials. So 'layout' and 'pages' are pointing to index files.
I tried deleting and reinstalling package.json along with deleting and reinstalling parcel. I also attempted to clear my parcel cache however I am not too sure if it actually worked. I spent an hour looking through all my sass modules trying to look for error but I was not able to find anything.
